# Scripting - Fetch actual remote config values

Tags: android, firebase-remote-config

We are using Remote Config in our Android project.

Current implementation - App downloads the values from Firebase Cloud asynchronously, and for first start uses default values which we configured manually and programmatically.

What I want in new implementation - Actual remote config values loads to some raw json resource file right before release, and app uses these values as initial default values. It may be some script code, or shell code that fetches remote config values from Firebase Cloud. I hope that I intelligibly describe a problem.

What I met during my research - Firebase Config REST API, but I'm not confident if that use case may be resolved by this one.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "loads to some raw json resource file right before release".  Are you expecting the app to do something before it's launched the first time?  Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: I think the question is referring to doing a build step that preloads the current remote config values into the app as the defaults.